# WindowsService calling an External CMD process

Tags: .net, windows-services

I developed a Windows Service Process called WSP, which is calling badly documented external Console Application developed by a big company, also known as External.exe.

My WSP runs each 2 hours without errors, calling External.exe which executes perfectly. Sometimes, I don't know why, External.exe finishes with an Error Code <> 0. As I said before, there is no documentation about it and it is random.

The problem is: When External.exe returns code <> 0, all subsequent calls to External.exe will fail.

To solve this, I have to restart WSP manually in Services.msc (yes, I tried to restart WSP programmatically, and as I know now, a Service cannot restart itself). After this, all steps in WSP work as expected.

Did anyone have this kind of problem?

```
   private static bool ExecuteCommandLineTransformProcess(string inputFullPath, string transformerCommandLine)
    {
        var success = false;
        var info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", transformerCommandLine);

        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;

        //Launching External.EXE tool with parameters
        using (var pr = Process.Start(info))
        {
            pr.WaitForExit();

            if (pr.HasExited)
            {            
                //pr.ExitCode is the return off external window process, expected 0 when no errorsfound
                success = pr.ExitCode == 0;
                                        
                if (pr.ExitCode != 0)
                { 
                    LoggerHelper.Log.Warn($"Transformer - Finished - ##With errors!!! : {pr.ExitCode} .");
                    //After This Error, all callings to External.Exe will fail silently (not working and ExitCode as 0)

                }

                LoggerHelper.Log.Info($"Transformer - Finished.");
                pr.Refresh();
            }
        }

        return success;
    }
```

I looked to TaskManager and External.Exe apparently is not running in Background;
I tried a workaround forcing a restart in WSP, but as I said, a WindowsService cannot restart itself;
And yes, I searched in stack overflow, Google, and Big Company Supply Docs.

I accept all ideas and thanks in advance

...

Update, I tried to force Throw New Except in case of ExitCode != 0 ... and surprise, the WSP still alive and not call restart WSP auto-restart. Searching about this, I've found a lot of suggestions like: "Create another Process to Force this to restart"; "Send CMD KillProcess to WSP" ... They are not options to me.

Now I'm testing another approach, I'm using WSP.Dispose() (which inherits from ServiceBase class) each execution finishing. By now, I've published WSP in tests environment and I still waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Service can restart itself using the options in the Recovery tab of the service properties:

[image]

When the external executable errs throw an exception which will terminate the service execution and the settings in the Recovery tab will kick in and restart the service...

You could also create another Windows Service that your "WSP" service would alert using  [IPC (Interprocess communications)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/interprocess-communications) if the External.exe returns code <> 0 and whose sole purpose would be to restart the "WSP" service upon that alert.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dean,

I knew how to restart/recovery services automatically on failure, but I don't know if this is a good practice.
In my case, pr.ExitCode != 0  is a possible result and I'm logging it. In another hand I chooses to  not throw a new Exception.
I thought it previously, but I'm not satisfied with this aproach

Answer (score 0):

My best guesses are:
- An info of the process is kept in memory, and is not being disposed correctly
- A file used by both your service and External.exe is getting locked, so External.exe fails because can't access it. When you restart the service, the lock is released and that fixes the issue.